# How can I get output code for Latex from my R code?

Tags: r, latex

```r
library(summarytools)
library(stargazer)
view(dfSummary(DataV2,graph.col = TRUE), method = "render")
```

Comment: You should include a reproducible example.  We don't have `DataV2`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `summarytools` has a way to produce LaTeX directly, but it can produce Markdown output, and the `rmarkdown` package can convert that to LaTeX.  For example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "17/02/2022"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results='asis'}
library(summarytools)
library(stargazer)
dfSummary(tobacco, 
          plain.ascii  = FALSE,
          style        = 'grid',
          graph.magnif = 0.85,
          varnumbers = FALSE,
          valid.col    = FALSE,
          tmp.img.dir  = "/tmp")  
```
````

Because I used the `keep_tex: true` option in the YAML, it outputs the .tex file as well as the PDF, and you could theoretically extract the LaTeX from there if you weren't using R Markdown for the rest of the document.  It might not be easy, because of all the embedded figures.